# Haskell fetch URL via browser

Tags: haskell, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I want to do some screen-scraping (from Netflix) in Haskell but the site requires a cookie login state, so most of the examples of this use browser automation to ask a logged-in browser to do the actual URL fetch, and then scrape from that text.

A good example of what I want to (in Ruby) is at: https://gist.github.com/1425290

Is there any simple way to do the equivalent from Haskell?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you can't just transliterate the Ruby code? (The `System.Process` module would probably help.)

Comment: Yes; the Ruby code uses JavaScript to drive the browser to fetch pages, which is what I asked about an alternate way to do on Windows since it doesn't support JS.

Comment: JavaScript definitely works on Windows... you are using it right now. That script actually uses Applescript, which *is* specific to OSX.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the correction, I usually get terminology confused when discussing Mac's!  :-)

Comment: It might be worth asking this as a language agnostic question ("what's a good way of screen scraping on windows?" or something), and then working out how to do it in Haskell.

Comment: Well, I think I already have a good Python solution example, and of course there are many ways to do it, but it is the browser automation issue that i am interested in seeing if there is a good Haskell solution for.

Answer (score 3):

I know off the top of my head that the [`HTTP`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP) package's `Network.Browser` supports cookies, as does [`curl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/curl). Presumably [`http-conduit`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit)'s `Network.HTTP.Conduit.Browser` is so-named because it, too, supports cookies, though I'm not 100% confident of that.

Comment: Thanks - I had seen this although not studied the details, but forcing an automated login and managing the cookies is notably more complicated than a manual logging-in and then just parsing the HTML for results. I did find a python example of doing this - and could mimic it, but it is easier to just adapt the python script to do the fetching I wanted. (http://jacob.hoffman-andrews.com/netflix-enqueue.py.txt) I was interested in implementing in Haskell just to see how easy it would be - the Ruby code is very compact!